# R interoperability - What other statistical packages can call R functions?

Tags: r, interop

I tried to find a list of the statistical packages & other data analysis software that allow calling R functions and recup their outputs in an integrated fashion, all of that "out-of-the-box" (that is, without any circumvoluted hacks).

[This document](http://r4stats.com/articles/calling-r/) enumerates *some* of them, but does claim exhaustivity in any way. I limited my search to software specialized in data analysis, thus excluding more generalist programming languages such as C++, Java or Python.

So far I found a good number of them, but I'm sure I missed a few. If you know one (or more) that I missed, I'm much interested in knowing, as I'm building an R course and this will be part of it. Thanks in advance.

My list so far:

**SPSS** (example from [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-call-r-spss/))

```
BEGIN PROGRAM R.
cat("\t\tHello R!\n")
END PROGRAM.
```

**SAS/IML** (example from this [pdf document](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug12/bb/bb10.pdf))

```
proc iml;
run ExportDataSetToR("Sashelp.Class", "dataframe" );
submit / R;
  names(dataframe)
  str(dataframe)
  summary(dataframe)
endsubmit;
quit;
```

**JMP** (example from [this page](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Working_with_R.shtml))

```
R Init( );
R Submit("
x <- 1:5
x
");
R Term( );
```

**Matlab** (example from [this blogpost](http://neurochannels.blogspot.ca/2010/05/how-to-run-r-code-in-matlab.html))

```
openR; %Open connection to R server
x=[1:50]; %create x values in Matlab
putRdata('x',x); %put data into R workspace
evalR('y<-sqrt(x)'); %evaluate in R
evalR('plot(x,y)') %plot in R
closeR;
```

**Matematica** also allows it since [version 9](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-integration-with-r/)

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
REvaluate["{
    set.seed(123)
    rnorm(10,10)
 }"]
```

**Statistica** allows it through various means as described in this [white paper](http://www.statsoft.com/Portals/0/Support/Download/White-Papers/R_Integration_White_Paper.pdf).

**Stata**: With a few tweaks you can get some results, but nothing really integrated though.

edit: As pointed in Steven Beaupré's comment:

**Tableau** offers a way to connect to a local installation of R-Server as describe [here](http://www.tableau.com/learn/whitepapers/using-r-and-tableau)

**Python** can also be used as a data analysis tool as pointed out by Carl Witthoft; [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python) gives some good examples of calls to R functions from Python.

Comment: I wouldn't exclude Python, given that a lot of folks use numpy/scipy for stats.

Comment: Perhaps you could add Tableau to your list http://www.tableau.com/new-features/r-integration - It integrates with R through Calculated Fields since version 8.1 - Example: `SCRIPT_INT(‘kmeans(data.frame(.arg1,.arg2,.arg3,.arg4),3)$cluster;', SUM([Petal length]), SUM([Petal width]),SUM([Sepal length]),SUM([Sepal width]))`

Comment: @Carl I saw many links having to do with "getting numpy data in R" but the other way around? It must exist, if you have some reference or example I can add it.

Comment: @Steven I added Tableau to the list, thx

Comment: Well I found 10 examples by googling "call R from python" ...

Comment: Hmmm seems a bit outside the scope of what I intended at first but I'll add it for sake of completeness,